# Is there a function to edit Blogs contents in Blogs page?

Tags: filters, child-theme, blog-page

Can I edit blogs output content in blogs page? What is the correct way to do it? I assume there must be a filter function, the name of which I don't know.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "blogs page?" Do you mean the default archive, which shows your latest posts in either full or excerpt form? Or are you working with a MultiSite with multiple blogs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter called [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) which you can use to do anything you like with the content. If you want to constrain this to certain pages, you must add an extra condition. It is not completely clear what you mean by 'blogs page'. The condition for the blogs home page is [`is_home`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) or else you might need [`is_archive`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/). Like this:

```
add_filter ('the_content','wpse280327_the_content');
function wpse280327_the_content ($content) {
  if (is_home) { 
    ... do stuff with $content ...
    }
  return $content;
  }
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need. I need a filter to edit EACH blog's content in blogs list page.

Comment: You mean you need a front-end editor? There are plugins that do this.

Comment: Nope, I mean there is a blogs page with list of blogs. 'the_content' is the content of whole page. I need a filter for each job separately